# How to authenticate as a Google Workspace user from an installed Google Marketplace SDK app?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

I am developing an app which uses Google Calendar APIs deployed on the Google Workspace Marketplace and installed on a Workspace by an administrator.

I'd like to list the calendars and events of all the workspace user. However, I can't find any documentation about it . The documentation usually gives examples about a User installed OAuth authorization or a service account with domain delegation - but nothing about an administrator installed app on a whole workspace.

Therefore, I have a few questions:

1. When an app is installed on a workspace, which credentials am I supposed to use ?
2. What does the installation of the app on a workspace by an administator unlocks ? Does the user still need to approve the permissions of the app ?
3. After the administrator has installed the app, can I perform requests (list events) on workspace users ?
4. With the googleapis npm package, how I am supposed to designate which workspace I'm requesting ? (ie. for a Users list request)

Any examples, documentation other than "[how to create a logo for your app](https://youtu.be/OpGsJl6QQHQ?si=0oo0cppR_byf3KJY&t=203)" or help will be much appreciated :)